# Docusign envelopes are blank

Tags: docusignapi

I created an envelope for embedded signing, but docusign displays blank pdf. User can still sign on it, but the document is itself blank.

sample pdfs used to create envelope -
- https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf

Comment: can you share the code you wrote? It's hard to tell what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

If the you think the PDF is causing a problem for DocuSign, try sending it for signature using the DocuSign web tool.

If that works, then the problem is in your application. There are some PDFs that DocuSign has trouble with, but they're quite rare.

Comment: It's working from DocuSign web tool. Seems like there is some problem with my application.